# Syntax error in Insert Statement but Insert Statement is fine

Tags: sql, syntax, insert

I'm receiving  a `"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"` when trying to submit this query.

```
INSERT INTO 
  Modified (ModifiedID, Username, Table, RecordID) 
VALUES 
  ('12','null','Accident','1')
```

All datatypes match in the database.  If I run the query without inserting into "Table", it works.  I don't know why, when I add the table string value to the query I receive the error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO Modified (ModifiedID, Username, [Table], RecordID) 
  VALUES ('12','null','Accident','1')
```

In most SQL dialects, TABLE is a RESERVED WORD.    The [] is Microsoft's delimiter and I believe backticks ` are used in MySQL

Also, do you really want 'null' as opposed to NULL, they have different meanings

Comment: +1. All points, and a nice catch on `'null'` (a string) vs. `NULL` (a non-value).

Comment: Ah reserved word. Thank you

Comment: Thanks also for the note about "null" and "NULL"

Comment: @user2444472: So that it's clear, the difference is **not** about lowercase vs. UPPERCASE. It has to do with the quotes (`'null'`) vs. the **lack of** quotes (`NULL`). The first is a character string, the other is an unknown (not set) value. They have totally different meanings.

Comment: Upvote for the catch on NULL. All too often I see (string)'null' in db tables when NULL should have been used and this can have severely unintended consequenses

Answer (score 0):

In HSQLDB:

```
INSERT INTO Modified (ModifiedID, Username, "Table", RecordID)
VALUES (12, NULL, 'Accident', 1);
```

I am just going to assume that "key-ish" sounding fields, eg. ModifiedID and RecordID, are supposed to be INTEGER or BIGINT rather than, say, VARCHAR.  DDL would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO Modified (ModifiedID, Username, `Table`, RecordID) 
VALUES ('12', NULL, 'Accident', '1')
```